# Pass an array to a PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

If I have this in JS:

```
{
    "48_2019-03-12" => {
        status: "Open",
        date: "2019-03-12",
        roomid: 48
    }, 
    "48_2019-03-20" => {
        status: "Close", 
        date: "2019-03-20", 
        roomid: 48
    }
}
```

I created it by using this:

```
var arr = new Map();
arr.set(roomid + '_' + date, {
    status: updatedStatus,
    date: date,
    roomid: roomid
});
```

What is the best way to pass this to a PHP page ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is JSON so you can just read it by json_decode http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: That's not an array. It looks more like an object

Answer (score 0):

You cannot paste JS into PHP directly, it should be sent as JSON data via AJAX request to PHP server.